# Missing write permission with a specific directory on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, permissions, login, windows-10

Recently, I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 dual-boot. Issue is, when I boot the PC and login directly in Ubuntu I can access the shared directory with only read-only access. But, if I reboot the PC and login Windows 10, access that directory & login again in Ubuntu 18.04 immediately, then I get the full access of the directory.

I need the full access of the directory every time I login Ubuntu. It is very annoying to login Windows 10 & then login Ubuntu to get the full access. How can I achieve that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could be a dirty filesystem, have you tried running fsck or equivalent? How are you dismounting it?

Comment: @ubfan1I haven't tried fsck or any equivalent. I have dismounted the directory using the little "Eject" icon from Nautilus and mounted again, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Also, check your Windows settings and make sure that "Turn on Fast Startup" is disabled.  Leaving that on can make it so that Windows keeps the drive in a hibernated state instead of closing it every time you turn off or reboot your system.  To check the drive in Windows, it is find the drive in Explorer and Right Click the drive and go to the tools and check your drive from there to make sure there are no problems in Windows.